# Self join in sql to get state wise total sale

Tags: sql

I have two tables:

- in `tab1`, I have username, password, stateofcountry
- in `tab2`, I have username, year, totalsale

The years may be `2016,2017,2018`.

I want to get stateofcountry wide total sale comparison for any two years.

For example:

```
state:2016:2017
st1  :2345:2345
st2  :237:789
```

and so on, for all states available in tab1

Comment: So you have tables, attribute values, and a tool. What is your [answerable programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Answer (score 0):

Use `group by` as I cant find anything what you have put in as a question just as a sample use `Select state_of_country, agg(records_you_want) from table group by state_of_country` (for aggregate category wise )

if not aggregate use subquery.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this is conditional aggregation:

```
select t1.stateofcountry,
       sum(case when t2.year = 2016 then totalsale else 0 end) as sales_2016,
       sum(case when t2.year = 2017 then totalsale else 0 end) as sales_2017
from tab1 t1 join
     tab2 t2
     on t1.username = t2.username
group by t1.stateofcountry;
```

Comment: DONE. IT WORKS
THANX